# How schedule events on the Netezza Events management

Tags: database, netezza

I want to undestand if the are some configuration to schedule the events rules that i have created, i follow the informations here [Text](https://manualzz.com/doc/o/lw1pa/ibm-netezza-system-administrator-s-guide-managing-event-rules?__cf_chl_tk=pdcd4ng2_ISaYjG3d2mAOGI8K3FIr0rcqLIWiELScB0-1671751446-0-gaNycGzNByU.)

the process that i follow it was :

1. I Copy and enable a template event rule
2. I Modified the message template, to send the report event by email

but the only doubt that may a dont understand is who schedule this events , if i want to run daily or since 7 days, can this scheduler ?

and my last question i can test my rules?

Answer (score 1):

> > who schedule this events

One does not schedule an event.  An **event** happens ... and then the system responds to the event (using the rule that you have set up).

e.g.,
notify me if the system goes offline
notify me if the disks are > 95% full

If you want something to occur at a regularly scheduled time, then linux's "cron" facility would seem to be the way to go.